# How to return from an AlertDialog to the AlertDialog before

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

How can I return from an `AlertDialog` which is called and offers more buttons and the user clicks on one of this buttons, then a new `AlertDialog` pops up with an input field. So if I check if the user input is e.g. numeric, how can I return to the `AlertDialog` offered before?

Comment: You have to pop up the first one again...

Comment: @RKN And how to achieve this? Is there a special function?

Comment: If you have not closed(i.e. you haven't called `dismiss()`) the first `AlertDialog`, it should be there when you call `dismiss()` on the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `DialogFragment` from the support library for each of these Dialogs.
Just add onClickListeners to each of the buttons of the first `DialogFragment` and show the second `DialogFragment` in `onClick`.

There should not be any necessity for checking if the input is a number if you just set the appropriate input type first.

When the user taps a button on the second `DialogFragment`, just call `dismiss()`.

Comment: And how can I do this with an AlertDialog, which has e.g. a button with an OnClickListener and if the users clicks on it  it opens up another dialog with a button and Listener. If the user clicks this button, it should return to the dialog before. I tried dismiss() in the second OnClickListener, but the dialog before is not displayed again.

Comment: As long as you don't call dismiss on the first DialogFragment, what I described above definitely works. I implemented it in one of my apps.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work with AlertDialog.Builder. If I click the button of the first dialog, it closes automatically and opens up the next dialog.

Comment: Create a subclass of DialogFragment for each of your Dialogs. In onCreateDialog, initialize the Dialog using your AlertDialog.Builder.